# GET POSTの表示のやり取りのテストができません

Tags: java, spring-boot

Java初心者です。

コントローラーにget postをセットしましたが、コンソールで結果が表示されません。
フォームで入力したIDとPASSWORDをコンソール上に表示させるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String S161formList(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("S100601formList", new S161formList());
        return "S161.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String form(@ModelAttribute 161formList 161formList1, Model model1) {

        System.out.println(id);
System.out.println(password);
        return "S161.html";
    }


    public class S161formList {

    private int id; 
    private int password;

各setter getter
}
```

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/profile/save}" method="post" th:object="${161formList}">
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 15%">
        <col style="width: 30%">
        <col style="width: 15%">
        <col style="width: 30%">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>ログインID<span class="">&nbsp;*</span></th>
            <td><input type="text" class="input-sm" value=""  name="id" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>パスワード</th>
            <td><input type="password" class=""  name="password"></td> 
        </tr></tbody>
</table></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ぱっと見では、コントローラーがビルドできないように見えます。コントローラーのソースコードは省略せずに記載した方がいいと思います。

Comment: package S161;

 public class S161formList {

    private int id; 
    private int password;

       
    public S161formList() {
        
        this.id=111 ;
        this.password=111 ;
        
    }


 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }



 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }


 public int getPassword() {
  return password;
 }




 public void setPassword(int password) {
  this.password = password;
 }


}

Comment: ありがとうございます。コントローラーがビルドできていない、、ｈｔｍｌと連携がとれていない？ということでしょうか？

Comment: 質問本文のソースコードの抜粋を見ると、コントローラーに`S161formList`という内部クラスを定義していて、メソッドでは`S`で始まらない`161formList`というクラスを使用しているように見えます。コントローラーとコントローラーで使用するクラスは省略せずに本文に記載した方が回答を得やすいと思います。

Comment: package 161; public class 161formList { private int id; private int password; public 161formList() { this.id=111 ; this.password=111 ; } public int getId() { return id; } public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; } public int getPassword() { return password; } public void setPassword(int password) { this.password = password; } }

Comment: すいません、これがただしいのですが、なかなか画面で入力した値がコンソール上に出なくて、、

Comment: id を変数に解決できません
 password を変数に解決できません
とエラーが出ました

Comment: ビルドエラーですね。ビルドエラーが解決しなければ、アプリは動作しません。まずは、なぜビルドエラーが起きているか1つずつ調べてみて下さい。

Comment: @123456 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、追加の情報は質問文に追記してみてください。コメント欄では改行が表示されないため、コードを貼るには不向きです。

Answer (score 1):

本質的な問題としては、

```
    model.addAttribute("S100601formList", new S161formList());
```

で属性名を `S100601formList` と設定しているので、これを意識する必要があります。

公式リファレンスとしては次のセクションが該当箇所になります:

- [@ModelAttribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) - 1.3.3. Handler Methods

`@ModelAttribute` で検索すると日本語で解説されているサイトも多くヒットすると思います。

修正後の一例としては[このような形](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/commit/380fc275ae18de4e3cce9b5802bafdb2a9f6c556?w=1)になります。